# há algum erro nesse código que eu fiz, "deixando a página para cima"

Tags: html, css

o código em si, está certo, mas quando eu o coloco em um , parece que o conteudo fica para cima, deixando os componentes seguintes para cima

preciso descobrir o erro:

```
.thumb {
    width:33%;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .thumb {
        float: none;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width: 100%;
        width:auto;
    }
}
```

e eu uso dessa forma para manter alinhado:

```
<div class="thumb">
    <img src="images/image" alt="" title=""/>
    <h3>TESTE</h3>
    <p>TESTE</p>
</div>
```

aí está o jsFiddle como solicitado:
[novo jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Leb6xom4/1/)

no primeiro momento parece estar tudo certo, porém quando você redimensiona a tela do jsFiddle, consegue ver o erro

preciso muito descobrir isso!!
alguem pode me ajudar??

Comment: Podes fazer um jsFiddle com um exemplo? e explicar o que está a falhar e com que resolução...

Comment: é o seguinte, o código está certo, como pode ver. Mas se eu adicionar algo a mais embaixo do código, vai tudo "para cima". Qual pode ser o erro??

Comment: Parece-me tudo bem no jsFiddle. O que é que não funciona para ti?

Comment: Sergio, fiz um novo exemplo para demonstrar o erro. Se voce redimensionar a pagina, conseguirá ver que está preto onde está branco. Como posso arrumar isso??

Comment: E qual é a correta? a horizontal ou vertical?

Comment: Voce tem que redimensionar a linha vertical para ficar com width maior de 800px, como no css @media

Comment: Eu sei isso. E dá resultados diferentes. A minha pergunta é: qual das partes a preto é a correta? quando está menor que 800px ou maior que 800px

Comment: está correta a parte menor que 800px. como pode ser demonstrado aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/Leb6xom4/2/

Comment: É assim que queres? https://jsfiddle.net/4rsr99sj/

Comment: sim, é isso mesmo!! muito obrigado!! nem me toquei que podia usar o inline-block. Coloque como resposta ali, por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de `float: left;` e `float: none;` podes usar `display: block;` e `display: inline-block;` e evitas os efeitos colaterais que o `float` gera.

Ficaria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/4rsr99sj/

```
.thumb {
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .thumb {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```